# Python HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request. Easy textbook example

Tags: python

Do you know what is going on?

With this code...

```
 import socket

 mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 mysock.connect(('www.py4inf.com', 80))
 mysock.send('GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')

 while True:
     data = mysock.recv(512)
     if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
         break
     print data;

 mysock.close()
```

I get the correct answer:

```
 %run "c:\users\miguel~1\appdata\local\temp\tmp6uahvi.py"
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: text/plain
 Content-Length: 167
 Connection: close
 Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2016 14:20:52 GMT
 Server: Apache
 Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Dec 2015 19:05:04 GMT
 ETag: "a7-526172f5b5d89"
 Accept-Ranges: bytes
 Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, content-type
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET

 [... Some random text ...]
```

The exercise now says to modify the example to be able to connect to pythonlearn.com and read a text file. I don't understand why I get a Bad Request error now...

```
 import socket

 mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 mysock.connect(('www.pythonlearn.com', 80))
 mysock.send('GET http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')

 while True:
     data = mysock.recv(512)
     if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
         break
     print data;

 mysock.close()
```

I get a **HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**

```
 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2016 14:31:19 GMT
 Connection: close
 Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d8fbb6ce8ae7a7163f9bcdb6ffd3c7c681472567479; expires=Wed, 30-Aug-17 14:31:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.pythonlearn.com; HttpOnly
 Server: cloudflare-nginx
 CF-RAY: 2da8f21c332550fe-MIA
```

Why? Thanks!

Comment: You should send the path to the server (the part starting with /code..), not the whole url. Also, it should be `\r\n`, not `\n`. Finally, you should send a `Host` header; many servers serve more than one domain.

Comment: Thanks Phillip however I wonder why it works with the example but not with exercise? How does it change with \r\n versus \n ?

Comment: Because the webserver at www.py4inf.com is more forgiving to standard violations than the other one. The specification requires you to use `\r\n`. Again, if it happens to work with `\n`, that's only because the particular webserver is forgiving with respect to standard violations.